# Build status icon for multibranch pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2, multibranch-pipeline

Can some one please provide details on How Build Status icons can be used in MultiBranch Pipeline to Put as a link on Github Pull request.

As multibranch pipeline has different PR builds, what is the right way to form the build status url in this case and link it to a PR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working.

As multi branch pipeline can have different branches for each PR, You need to explicitly specify the PR branch id in your Build status command in order to get it working.

See reference below:

`[![Build Status](https://jenkins.com/buildStatus/icon?job=folder/job/PR-id&build=1)](https://jenkins.com/job/folder/job/PR-2338/1/)`

You can make this URL part of PR in order to see the real time status of your build.